# WinWord2007 - is there any direct VBA-access to the style instance count of the style window?

Tags: vba, styles, ms-word

Inside the style window, when you click on the pull-down menue of a style and the style has been assigned anywhere within the document you are immediately being shown an instance-count of that style and are offered the possibility to select or delete all instances. If the style has not been assigned anywhere, these options are being greyed out.

I need this information inside a VBA-Program, but I have not found any convenient way of obtaining it, although WinWord seems to have it constantly available under it's fingertips.

As a work-around I have modified the "DeleteUnusedStyles"-Macro from [Tech-Tav.com](http://www.tech-tav.com/products/tech-tav-macro-suite/functionality), but my code is so slow, that processing the ca 350 built-in Microsoft styles becomes unpractical - and as it stands now, the macro doesn't even count the instances a certain style has been assigned, but only within which story range it has been assigned at all. Counting each individual instance this way would make the macro run for more than an hour:

In case that there is no direct way of obtaining the needed information from within VBA (and I have researched in vain for over a week now), could someone give me a hint how to speed up the search routine?

The routine needs the following information:

```
Dim iStyle% '(the number of the style which is to be processed)
```

and hands back the following information:

```
Dim V_NumberOfStylesFound% '(how many styles have been found within the document)
Dim Dim A_StylesUsedInDoc() As String '(An array containing all styles which have been used as base style)
Dim V_BaseStych leListedWhere '(A string listing the Story ranges whithin which the style has been found)


Sub S_SearchForStylesInDocument(V_NumberOfStylesFound, A_StylesUsedInDoc, iStyle, V_BaseStyleListedWhere)
Dim R_MyRange, R_MyStory As Range
Set O_MyStyle = ActiveDocument.Styles(iStyle)
V_iNameLocal = ActiveDocument.Styles(iStyle).NameLocal
V_iBaseStyle = ActiveDocument.Styles(iStyle).BaseStyle
V_ListedWhere = ""

StatusBar = iStyle & " Examining Story Ranges"
For Each R_MyStory In ActiveDocument.StoryRanges
    Set R_MyRange = R_MyStory
    'StatusBar = iStyle & " Examining " & F_ResolveStoryName(R_MyStory.StoryType) & "..."
        R_MyRange.Find.ClearFormatting
        R_MyRange.Find.Style = ActiveDocument.Styles(O_MyStyle)
        With R_MyRange.Find
            .Text = ""
            .Replacement.Text = ""
            .Forward = True
            .Wrap = wdFindContinue
            .Format = True
         End With
         If R_MyRange.Find.Execute Then
            StatusBar = iStyle & " Examining Styles Found"
            Select Case V_NumberOfStylesFound
            Case 0
                If V_iBaseStyle <> "" And V_iBaseStyle <> V_iNameLocal Then
                    V_NumberOfStylesFound = V_NumberOfStylesFound + 1
                    A_StylesUsedInDoc(V_NumberOfStylesFound) = V_iBaseStyle
                End If
            Case Is > 0
                Dim i%, Vb_IsListed As Boolean
                Vb_IsListed = False

                If Vb_IsListed = False Then 'found style is not yet listed
                    Dim j%, Vb_IsBaseStyleListed As Boolean
                    'StatusBar = V_iNameLocal & " style is in use."
                    For j = 1 To V_NumberOfStylesFound 'check whether the base style to found style is already listed?
                        If A_StylesUsedInDoc(j) = V_iBaseStyle Then
                            j = V_NumberOfStylesFound
                            Vb_IsBaseStyleListed = True
                        End If
                    Next j
                    If Vb_IsBaseStyleListed = False And V_iBaseStyle <> "" Then 'base style to found style is not yet listed
                        V_NumberOfStylesFound = V_NumberOfStylesFound + 1
                        A_StylesUsedInDoc(V_NumberOfStylesFound) = V_iBaseStyle
                        'StatusBar = V_iBaseStyle & " style is in use."
                    End If
                Else
                    'Stop 'how can style get listed twice?
                End If
                V_BaseStyleListedWhere = V_ListedWhere & R_MyStory.StoryType & ","
            End Select
         Set R_MyRange = R_MyStory
         End If
Next R_MyStory
'Stop
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you could use the [Style.InUse Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/bb211265%28v=office.12%29.aspx) to quickly find whether a style has been used and then Find to get the instance count.

Comment: Sorry for the German - Here it is again in English: 

Style.InUse does not inform me whether a style has actually been applied or not. In the description they write correspondingly _"The InUse property doesn't necessarily indicate whether the style is currently applied to any text in the document."_ If, for example, I modify an inbuilt style - no matter whether I'll apply or don't apply it to any text - it will be flaged as "inUse". It seems that there is no way around conducting a style search, which then has to be repeated for all story ranges.

Comment: OK, but it should still accelerate your search by eliminating the styles which have not been used or modified.

Comment: That certainly sounds right. Unfortunately ALL my styles are marked as "inUse", even though I have used just a fraction of them. So, examining this property won't make any difference. I have to find another way of accellerating the loop.

Comment: I'm sorry to hear that. Good luck!